# How to switch default True to False on specifying and argument?

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import optparse

p = optparse.OptionParser()
p.add_option("-o", action="store", dest="outfile")
p.add_option("-d", action="store_true", dest="debugflag")
p.set_defaults(debugflag=True)

opts,args = p.parse_args()

print opts, " ", args
print opts.outfile, opts.debugflag
```

Output:

```
$ ./optparseexample.py -o myfile -d
{'outfile': 'myfile', 'debugflag': True}   []
myfile True

$ ./optparseexample.py -o myfile 
{'outfile': 'myfile', 'debugflag': True}   []
myfile True
```

Question:

How to I switch the default value for debugflag from `True` to `False` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `action=store_false` then.

```
p.add_option("-d", action="store_false", dest="debugflag")
```

Please try to read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#action) before asking.

Comment: I am trying to set default as True and switch it to False when option is received.

Comment: That's not what you're asking, please edit your question. I edited my answer. AND, it's still obvious from the documentation. =)